# Sort the Parent object based on a child element inside a NSSet of the parent object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a coredata object graph relationship of one to many where one Account could have many Logs (Account<->>Logs). My objective is to sort the array of Accounts that i get from the fetch request, based on the child object's value which is a date inside my Log

```
extension Account {
 @NSManaged public var account_id: String?
 @NSManaged public var logs: NSSet?
}

extension SalesLogs {
 @NSManaged public var created_date: String?
 @NSManaged public var is_modified: Bool

}
```

My attempt was as bellow. I wants to compare the last created_date of each Account, and returns a sorted Accounts array

```
 let fetchData : [Accounts]= try StorageManager.shared.fetchData(entity: "SalesLogs", model: SalesLogs.self)
 let sorted array:[Accounts] = fetchData.filter{($0.logs?.allObjects as! [SalesLogs]).map {$0.created_date ?? "" > }.last == [true]}
```

Comment: sets are unordered

Comment: yes but u can cast all objects in a NSSet

Comment: You're probably looking for `.sort` or `.sorted` method; not `.filter`

Comment: @NewDev can u write the code snippet please im stuck

Comment: To sort an array, you would use `.sort` to sort in-place, or `.sorted` to return a sorted array, like this: `let sorted = [3,4,1,0].sorted(by: { $0 > $1 })`, which will sort from highest to lowest. In your case, you'd need to figure out how you'd want to find the log per account that you could use to compare with another account

Comment: @NewDev i tried and falied.. 

let arr = fetchData.sorted { (ff, gg) -> Bool in
            (dateFormater1.date(from: (ff.logs?.allObjects as! [SalesLogs]).last?.created_date ?? "")?.compare(dateFormater1.date(from: (gg.logs?.allObjects as! [SalesLogs]).last?.created_date ?? "")!) == .none)
        }

Comment: Are you trying to sort by the last log entry? You should know that sets are unordered, so getting `.last` isn't going to give you what you want. Also, dates can be compared with with `<` or `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to determine which of the logs dates you want to sort by. If it's the latest, then you'd need to find it first.

I suggest you update your `SalesLogs` to actually deal with dates instead of strings, because you could easily compare dates and find the maximum (i.e latest).

```
extension SalesLogs {

   var createdDate: Date {
      let formatter = DateFormater()
      formatter.dateFormat = ...

      // I'm avoiding an optional Date for simplicity
      return formatter.date(from: self.created_date ?? "") ?? Date.distantPast
   }
}
```

Armed with that, you'd need to find the latest date in a set, and use that to sort the array:

```
let sorted = fetchData.sorted { a, b in

   let logsA = a.logs as? Set<SalesLogs>
   let logsB = b.logs as? Set<SalesLogs>

   // find the latest (aka max) createdDate
   let dateA = logsA?.map{ $0.createdDate }.max{ $0 < $1 }
   let dateB = logsB?.map{ $0.createdDate }.max{ $0 < $1 }

   return (dateA ?? Date.distantPast) < ( dateB ?? Date.distantPast)
}
```