# Sort coredata Array based on a NSSet attribute

Tags: ios, swift

I have a coredata Array that has one to many relationship where one Account could have many Logs (Account<->>Logs). My objective is to sort the Account array, based on a child attribute value which is a date inside my Log. So far what i have tried and fail as bellow.

```
  func sortBy(types:[String],clonedAccountArray:[Account]) {

     let dateFormater1 = DateFormatter()
     dateFormater1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"


      let arr = clonedAccountArray.sorted { (acc1, acc2) -> Bool in
        (dateFormater1.date(from: (acc1.logs?.allObjects as! [SalesLogs]).last?.created_date ?? "")?.compare(dateFormater1.date(from: (acc2.logs?.allObjects as! [SalesLogs]).last?.created_date ?? "")!) == .none)
      }

  }
```

Hence this gives an exception saying "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". However i believe my sorting code is wrong. Any insights would much appreciate to find the erro

Comment: It's basically [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62560606/sort-the-parent-object-based-on-a-child-element-inside-a-nsset-of-the-parent-obj), slightly modified, while the previous one wasn't still answered. Why? It doesn't help to get an answer. I'd say it has an opposite effect.

Comment: Please, stop overusing tags, why `swift3`, `swift5` & `objective-c`? `swift` is enough and it has nothing to do with Objective-C.